# RoR Voting system working locally but not when deployed on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

My app implements ‘ideas’ that users can vote on and 'unvote'. It works fine locally. When pushed to Heroku, users can vote but the 'unvote' action does not work and generates a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page from herokuapp.com.

I've checked the heroku logs and the error is as follows :

```
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/ideas/remove_vote/1/1" for 88.171.195.199 at 2012-05-25 09:47:18 +0000
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by IdeasController#remove_vote as HTML
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"mJ5daJfBhf+823VTg9C1+YSBdqVFTFPuJWiO2cIx6iQ=", "u_id"=>"1", "i_id"=>"1"}
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: : DELETE FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."" = $1):
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/ideas_controller.rb:85:in `remove_vote'
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: DELETE FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."" = $1
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /ideas/remove_vote/1/1] invalidate, pass
2012-05-25T09:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

My `remove_vote` method in ideas_controller.rb is the following :

```
def remove_vote
  @vote = Vote.find_by_user_id_and_idea_id(params[:u_id], params[:i_id])
  @vote.destroy
  redirect_to ideas_path
end
```

Would any of you have an idea to fix this? I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the local database is SQLite and the production one on Heroku is PostgreSQL but I find it strange that adding a vote works and that removing one does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the delete statement being issued in that log: `DELETE FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."" = $1`

What column is that where clause talking about? What column should it be talking about? Is there anything in the Vote model that explains it not using the id column?

Comment: There was indeed : the migration that creates the votes included  'create_table :votes, :id => false do |t|' which prevented an 'id' column to be created, at least in the PG production database. Many thanks for helping me look there @Iain. I removed ', :id => false' and it now works very well.  Was it obvious that it would work well locally on the SQLite database and not on the PostgreSQL database ? Does that mean that the above mentionned migration does create an 'id' in SQLite but not on PostreSQL databases ?  (@Iain : thanks for editing my question too. I learnt a lot...)

Comment: It's not that your migrations creates an id in SQLite, per se; SQLite just adds a RowID to every table, ever, which I guess the rails' SQLite adapter is smart enough to use. And as to obviousness, things working differently on different databases is not obvious before they give you problems, and very obvious afterwards.

Comment: (and for what it's worth, thanks for the edit are due to [Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt), not me)

Comment: Thanks a lot @muistooshort. I did not know that. This relieves the frustration I had for not being yet in a position to +1 the answers I received (I still have to wait until my reputation is >15).

Answer (score 1):

When you run into issues like this it is a good idea to configure/run your application locally using postgres. This will allow you to debug these issues locally rather than trying to 'guess' what the problem is on Heroku.

Here is a good railscast on getting postgres running locally.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Lumbee. Looks like a good idea because even if I finally managed to fix the issue (see my comment to @Iain), this guessing did take a while...